# Mongoid: copyDatabase

Tags: mongoid

How I can use [copyDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) function, through `Mongoid`?

```
# something like that
::Mongoid::Sessions.default.command('copyDatabase','production','staging')
```